# JVM crashed with Problematic frame: V [libjvm.so+0x437ce7] ciObjectFactory::create_new_metadata(Metadata*)+0x327

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, jvm-crash

I have java application running on tcserver, which is a spring server based on tomcat-7.0.47. There are multiple of such applications running on a machine which has `64CPUs and 500G RAM`. I have latest version of java i.e. 1.8.0_91. All the applications keep crashing and mostly due to the same error  -

**# Problematic frame:

## V  [libjvm.so+0x437ce7] ciObjectFactory::create_new_metadata(Metadata*)+0x327**

**Current thread (0x00007f6075ebd800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=23187, stack(0x00007f602441c000,0x00007f602451d000)]**

Comment: There are a lot issues in bug tracker https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078731 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134389 They are closed as Cannot Reproduce. Try to change java version from 8 to 9

Comment: Technically 1.8.0_91 is not the latest, that is 1.8.0_92; I suggest that you upgrade to a newer version of Tomcat 7 (7.0.47 is from 2013, before the Java 8 release in March 2014) or even to Tomcat 8.

Comment: could you provide complete stacktrace for the thread ?

Answer (score 0):

In your crash reports

> Current CompileTask

is always same method ?
You can exclude method from JIT compilation via flag
`-XX:CompileCommand`.
See examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html).
You can also run vm with `-client` compiler

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue in JDK8 and JDK9, it is being triaged https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134389, you need to wait for this to get it fixed and get updated in upcoming releases.